# how do I undo all changes in my local rep and make it clone of upstream in github

Tags: git, github

on Github there is a repo, e.g github.com/foo/bar (==upstream)

I fork it to github.com/memo/bar (==origin)

I clone that to my hdd

Over the course of x days I pull from upstream, edit and push to origin.

My questions are:

1. Now I would like to undo all of my changes, and make my local master (and origin/master) identical to upstream/master. How do I do this? I have tried reset --hard upstream/master, but then I cannot push to origin.
2. Alternatively, I'd like to create a brand new branch containing my modded version (E.g. experimental_memo) and then make my master branch identical to upstream/master

If I didn't have the github fork (origin), I would just clone from scratch, but then I can't push, so the only solution I've found is to delete my fork on github, then re-fork, re-clone etc!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have no users of your fork you can simply `git push -f` after resetting to origin. This will break existing clones though so it should only be used if you are certain no one else is using your fork.

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems a bit hazy.

Of course you cannot push without `--force` after hard resetting to a new upstream. Use --force to alleviate that (but mind the users of your own fork if any)

I *think* you might wish to rebase your 'modded version' (changes) onto the new upstream:

```
git rebase upstream/master
```

This will still rewrite your branch history, but it will re-apply all your mods